# Setting up Kong Development Environment is failing

Tags: lua, kong

I am trying to Set-up a development environment of Kong. I have Kong & cassandra installed in my machine and able to run Kong Fine. I am facing problem when I am trying to set-up the development environment.

First I tried the Source Install as mentioned [here](https://github.com/mashape/kong#source-install).

**Issue1**

Execution of `sudo make install` in the directory in which Kong github repo was cloned gave me the following message:-

```
Use --force to force removal (warning: this may break modules).
Failed removing.
Updating manifest for /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks
kong 0.4.2-1 is now built and installed in /usr/local (license: MIT)
```

After that execution of `sudo make dev` failed with the below error:-

```
bin/kong config -c kong.yml -e TEST
lua: bin/kong:13: module 'kong.cli.utils' not found:
    no field package.preload['kong.cli.utils']
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/kong/cli/utils.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/kong/cli/utils/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/kong/cli/utils.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/kong/cli/utils/init.lua'
    no file './kong/cli/utils.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/kong/cli/utils.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/kong/cli/utils/init.lua'
    no file './kong/cli/utils.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/kong/cli/utils.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/kong/cli/utils.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/kong/cli/utils.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
    no file './kong/cli/utils.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/kong.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/kong.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/kong.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
    no file './kong.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    bin/kong:13: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
make: *** [dev] Error 1
```

Then I tried the vagrant install which also failed.

**Issue 2**

After executing the below command:-

```
KONG_PATH=/home/j/code/github.com/kong vagrant up
```

I got the following error:-

```
There is a syntax error in the following Vagrantfile. The syntax error
message is reproduced below for convenience:

/home/j/code/github.com/kong-vagrant/Vagrantfile:17: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8000, host: 8000
                                           ^
/home/j/code/github.com/kong-vagrant/Vagrantfile:18: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8001, host: 8001
                                           ^
/home/j/code/github.com/kong-vagrant/Vagrantfile:20: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
```

Can someone let me know what is going wrong?

Environment

- Lua - 5.2.0
- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - 64 Bit

Comment: As You can see, [Kong dev version fails to build](https://travis-ci.org/Mashape/kong). Have You tried latest **released** version? something like this:  `git clone https://github.com/Mashape/kong.git && git checkout tags/0.2.4`

Comment: Tried that also. But getting the same error still. `git reflog --decorate -1` displays `3dd3862 (HEAD, tag: 0.4.2) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to tags/0.4.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Issue 1 was because I was using Lua 5.2. Kong supports only  Lua 5.1
  as mentioned [here](https://getkong.org/install/source/)
- Issue 2 was because of the Vagrant version. `Kong-vagrant` works only
  with Vagrant 1.7 onwards.